# Receive an read SMS with correct encoding and convert to UTF8

Tags: android, utf-8, character-encoding, broadcastreceiver, sms

I am writing a BroadcastReceiver to receive SMS messages. I will need to compare the message with a string that was set by the user in the settings, but the string can be non-ASCII. The below code works only for SMS-es that contain only ASCII characters. How can I convert the message to UTF8 encoding?

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    final static String TAG = "SmsReceiver";

    public SmsReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        try {
            if (bundle != null) {
                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                    final SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    final String senderNum = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    final String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                    Log.i(TAG, "senderNum: " + senderNum + "; message: " + message);
```

update:

it seems that the same code works on my Nexus5, but doesn't work in the emulator with API 10.

The text I sent: `שלום`

The text I received: `éRΨ¿Ñ u$`

Comment: Why do you want UTF-8? Java doesn't use UTF-8 for strings. What doesn't work when non-ASCII chars are used?

Comment: When I send an SMS from one emulator to another, and print the message to the log (last line in my code) the message is "garbage". See also my update

Comment: Sounds like it's just your logger. Please show the "garbage" log line and possibly a UTF-16 hex encode of your string

Comment: Well, it looks like it's not the logger, but the old (API 10) emulator has some bug, because now I looked at the SMS in the Message app, and they show up exactly like in my app.

Comment: ok, so what does "garbage" look like and what is the original string?

Comment: I added it to the question. The received string is copy&pasted from logcat. If you need it in another format let me know how to do it from a String.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, if someone else gets into similar problems, it seems to be a bug in the emulators. I opened a ticket for android emulator: 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202723