# Sending SMS between emulators

Tags: android, android-emulator, sms

I am trying to send SMS from emulator to emulator. It works, but only with a very limited characterset (subset of ASCII). If I have any of the following characters in the message, anything after the 1st occurrence of these characters will become gibrish:

```
|, ^, {, }, €, [, ~, ] and \
```

(But I'll also need non-ASCII characters like Hebrew alphabet)

For example if I send `Hello ^ World` it'll become `Hello ^`.

Or `[Hello:World]` becomes something like `[ e   ]`

This is the code I use:

```
void sendSms(final String toNumber, final String message) {
    final SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
    if (message.getBytes().length <= 160) {
        sm.sendTextMessage(toNumber, null, message, null, null);
    } else {
        ArrayList<String> msgStringArray = sm.divideMessage(message);
        sm.sendMultipartTextMessage(toNumber, null, msgStringArray, null, null);
    }
    Log.v(TAG, "sendSms: " + toNumber + ", " + message + ", " + message.length() + " chars / " + message.getBytes().length + " bytes");
}
```

The code I use to receive the messages is here: [Receive an read SMS with correct encoding and convert to UTF8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35797212/receive-an-read-sms-with-correct-encoding-and-convert-to-utf8)

Comment: "Receive an read SMS with correct encoding and convert to UTF8" has no accepted answer - did you copy the "buggy code" - which describes a encoding problem....

Comment: It is also my question. At the beginning I thought it's a problem with receiving, now it looks that it's even sending. Or somewhere in between.. Who knows... I also filed a bug report to android: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202723

Comment: SMS uses 7 bit ascii.  That means very basic characters only.  You need to call sendMultipartTextMessage to get it to work with unicode.  sendTextMessage doesn't send the special configuration data needed to tell the carrier that it isn't 7 bit ascii

Comment: @GabeSechan Unfortunately it doesn't work either. I just commented out the if in the above code, but it behaves exactly the same.

Comment: Googling for it, I'm seeing a lot of reports that its broken on emulators but working on devices.  Have you tried a real device as a sanity check?

Comment: I'll try later, when I can put my hands on my wife's phone

Comment: @GabeSechan, yes it works on real devices

Comment: Facing same issue, it works on real devices but not on emulators.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug in the emulators: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202723

> Though I don't have an immediate solution, it is worth mentioning that
>   Emulator 2.0 includes a UI for sending SMS messages to the virtual
>   device, and the aforementioned characters all work fine when sent from
>   that UI. If you need to do some testing with a device receiving (but
>   not sending) an SMS message containing those characters, that should
>   do the trick until we track down this bug. You can get access to
>   Emulator 2.0 from the preview release channel as part of tools 25.0.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I was unable to undelete the answer after I "tailored" it to this question, so I added a new answer